# Custom action to set emblem in thunar

Tags: thunar

I'm on Xubuntu 11.10 and currently trying to use emblems in Thunar to mark which videos in a folder I've already watched.

The problem is I can't find any terminal command to do so and neither can I change the properties of multiple files in Thunar as the context menu item 'properties' is greyed out as soon as I select more than one file.

The command 'gvfs-set-attribute' which works with Nautilus doesn't do anything in Thunar. I guess Thunar stores the meta-data in some other way.

Can anyone tell me how to either set the emblems with a custom command (better solution) or change multiple file properties in Thunar?

Answer (score 4):

[Thunar](http://thunar.xfce.org/) saves its metadata in a special file. You can find it at `$HOME/.cache/Thunar/metafile.tbd`.

This is a database and can be accessed using `tbdtool` (that is part of `tdb-tools`)

Use it like this:

```
tdbtool $HOME/.cache/Thunar/metafile.tdb
```

To show the contents of the database use the `dump` command.

> **dump**
>             Dump the current database as strings.

In your question you also wanted to insert emblems. You can use `insert` for this:

> **insert** *KEY* *DATA*
>             Insert a record into the current database.

Comment: This answer apparently doesn't work in recent versions of Ubuntu http://askubuntu.com/questions/408743/set-emblems-in-thunar-in-script?lq=1