# How to place custom icons (not emblems) on folders in Thunar

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, thunar

(This is **not** a duplicate as [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79110/how-can-i-assign-custom-icons-to-folders) describes how to add custom icons to folders in `Nautilus`, whereas there seems to be no explanation for `Thunar`.)

In `Nautilus` (as [this questions shows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79110/how-can-i-assign-custom-icons-to-folders)) there is the fun feature of being able to place any custom icon onto a folder by just right clicking the folder, clicking the folder in the menu that comes up and selecting a custom icon.

However in `Thunar` I can only seem to add emblems (see the screenshot below) and not actual custom icons (I have a folder of them scaled to the right sizes ready to use).
I have looked round the `Thunar` settings and general Xfce `settings-editor` but have not been able to see a way of setting a custom icon on a folder. This [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97598/custom-action-to-set-emblem-in-thunar) only describes how to add a custom emblem in `Thunar`, which is different.

My home folder in `Thunar` with *emblems* but not *custom icons*:

[image: Home folder]

Comment: I doubt Thunar even supports that feature. It only supports Emblems, for whatever that is worth.

Comment: There was the `.directory` thing, but thats probably KDE only: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036046/programmatically-set-custom-folder-directory-icon-in-linux

Comment: Custom Thumbnails for folders are now possible with Thunar 1.8.2 or above. Please check the Wiki for details: https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/tumbler

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This feature request has come up on the mailing-lists several times, and was quite recently proposed [in this discussion](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.desktop.xfce.thunar.devel/4173). However, the answer from Simon Steinbeiß, an active xfce and xubuntu developer, was that:

> You can use either emblems (right-click > properties > emblems) or the user-dirs (the fixed list of user
>   directories can be found and modified in ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs). No support for custom
>   folder-icons at the moment.

There is a discussion at the [xfce forum](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=6687) on how thunar custom icons could be accomplished, and a patch has even been [submitted](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/attachment.cgi?id=4096) for thunar. It is explained that the patch

> scans the
>   thumbnaill dir and loads a custom icon if there's a file that matches
>   the file name on the desktop. So a file on the desktop named foo
>   will have a custom icon loaded if the image in the .thumbnails dir
>   is foo.gif

However, one of the leading xfce developers, Nick Schermer, has commented that

> Non md5hash files in the .thumbnails directory is a bad idea.
>     The prefix-only check if a bit flawed as well, it can be improved with a dot-check (so foo2.png is not matched).

So the method as described in the patch has not really been validated by the developers, and because it would involve a lot of time compiling thunar and its dependencies (as noted [here](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/building)), and then a lot of risk in installing them to your system, I would advise against trying it. You could experiment of course in a virtualised environment (virtualbox) or on a computer set aside for development, but not on a stable system.

It is usually fine to compile programs and apply patches, as I have discussed in many examples on this site, but on this occasion it is better to wait until a solution is available that has been validated by the developers.

For now the question is 'solved', but I will continue to update it and indeed research the issue to see how it could be accomplished in the manner that it is done in `Nautilus`.

Comment: Custom Thumbnails for folders are now possible with Thunar 1.8.2 or above. Please check my answer for details.

Answer (score 6):

The best workaround is to create the desired "launcher" on the desktop in application launcher you can set a custom icon, even pick a file from your own collection.

The command of the launcher should be set to `thunar <desired directory>`

Then cut + paste the launcher to the desired location.

Answer (score 1):

Custom folder icons can be configured via thumbler with Thunar 1.8.2 or above.

You can add a custom thumbnailer specialized for folder.

Check the section"Customized Thumbnailer for folders" in the [Thunar Wiki](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/tumbler/available_plugins#customized_thumbnailer_for_folders) for details.

For more details, check the [related bug](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14576)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Implementing the scripts at the wiki worked immediately.

Answer (score 0):

For desktop folders, the solution I discovered by accident is as follows:

Find the icon you want your folder to have. It must be a .png file. Change the extension to .jpg. Change the file name to 'folder'. (So the png file should be named 'folder.jpg'.

I am using Linux Mint Xfce 18.1.