# How do I set emblems in Thunar without the GUI?

Tags: thunar

I would like to add emblems to a file in Thunar using a script, but I can't find any documentation on this.

Is it possible to do this? And if so, how?

The same question was asked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97598/custom-action-to-set-emblem-in-thunar), but they mention a `~/.cache/Thunar/metafile.tdb` file which does not exist on my system. I think that question and the answer are outdated.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't exist? `~/.cache` is a hidden file you know..

Comment: `~/.cache/Thunar/` doesn't even exist. Not even after adding an emblem to a file in Thunar. I have Thunar version 1.6.3 installed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thunar, since version 1.6, has started using the gvfs-metadata daemon to store metadata.  The metadata is stored in `~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata`, however you can't read it from the files (it's [stored in some binary format](https://github.com/GNOME/gvfs/blob/master/metadata/file-format.txt) I think). In order to read metadata you use the `gvfs-info` command like this:

```
gvfs-info -a metadata:: /some/location
```

Which will print out the metadata of `/some/location`.

If you want to change metadata you can use the `gvfs-set-attribute` command like this:

```
gvfs-set-attribute /some/location -t stringv metadata::mdtype value
```

`/some/location` is the location of the file/folder whose metadata you want to edit, `-t stringv` tells the command to expect string input, `mdtype` sets the type of metadata you want to change (e.g. `emblems`) and `new value` sets `value` as the metadata for `mdtype`. For example:

```
gvfs-set-attribute Downloads -t stringv metadata::emblems emblem-default
```

Gives the `Downloads` folder the `default` emblem.

Set the value to `none` to remove emblems. You will have to restart the file manager to see the changes.

---

I wrote a small script that allows you to change the emblem of more than one folder/file at a time:

```bash
run() {    
cd # make sure we're in the home directory
echo 'What emblem do you want to apply?'
read emblem

if ! [ -z $emblem ]; then
    for i in $@
    do
        echo 'Changing stuff...'
        $(gvfs-set-attribute $i -t stringv metadata::emblems $emblem)
    done
    echo 'Done!'
else
    echo 'Emblem must be specified! Exiting...'
    exit  
fi
}

init() {

if [[ -z $@  ]]; then
    echo "No arguments provided"
else   
    run $@
fi
}

init $@
```

#### Sources:

- [The Nautilus mailing list](https://www.mail-archive.com/nautilus-list@gnome.org/msg06040.html)
- [Thunar FAQ](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/faq)
- [How to change icon/emblem of a directory from bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180432/how-to-change-icon-emblem-of-a-directory-from-bash)

Comment: @RemcoHaszing Please check my edited answer, I made an error and have now corrected it.

Comment: I wanted to know, because I wanted to write a script which sets the emblems to indicate the status of my Dropbox folders. I found out that I have to restart Thunar in order to see the newly added emblems and read this afterwards in your updated answer. Do you know whether Thunar can pick up these changes while running somehow?

Comment: @RemcoHaszing No, that's really not possible AFAIK. Thunar would have to continually poll for changes and that would take a lot of resources. I could edit the script to close all running instances of Thunar and open a new instance at your Dropbox folders, depending on what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Very nice script and command. This works perfectly on files and directories. However, my Dropbox folder is its own partition /dev/sda2 but it mounts at ~/Dropbox. I tried setting the emblem for ~/Dropbox but it didn't work. Any ideas?  Thank you

Comment: @jbrock Did you restart the file manager? The changes don't take affect until it is restarted. If that doesn't solve it then I'm afraid I don't know. You could try asking a new question. I'd love to help, but I currently lack the resources to test this specific issue. Sorry!

Comment: I only needed to unmount the partition. Then it worked just as the other directories and files did. Thank you so much for posting this! :)

Comment: @jbrock I'm glad you got it working, although a little confused as to why unmounting it was necessary.. Glad it works!

Comment: @Seth: It is a bit mysterious. To remount 'sudo mount -a' immediately removed the emblem on the folder. Then I unmounted and reset it the emblem and remounted using the sidebar in Thunar. This time the emblem stayed, but when I opened the home directory in Thunar a few minutes later, Thunar had replaced it with a different emblem from the options under Properties > Emblems. Oh well, I am glad it works for the other files and directories though.