# Add Custom Emblem in Thunar, Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, thunar

I would like to add my own custom emblems in Thunar, Xubuntu 14.04. I have created the necessary 10x10, 16x16, 22x22, etc. png files for my emblem and copied them here at their corresponding directories for the icon theme I am using, elementary Xfce darkest. For example `my-emblem22x22.png` was copied to each of the following and so forth for each size.

```
/usr/share/icons/elementary-xfce-darkest/actions/22
/usr/share/icons/elementary-xfce/emblems/22
/usr/share/icons/elementary-xfce/actions/22
```

However, after logging out and in again my custom emblem does not appear in Thunar. Any ideas? Much thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [this link](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=9449), I think it will tell you how to accomplish your objective.

> How does one create emblems to work with Thunar?
>
> [...] Add the correct files to the "emblems" folder of your icon theme. Make sure you prefix the name of the file with "emblem-" and run "gtk-update-icon-cache" on the theme's directory file containing the "index.theme" file. Should show up immediately.

Comment: Please include essential parts of the solution. Links might break some day

Answer (score 1):

Based on [ManyRoads's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/623601/1577831):

- Create an emblem image file; filename should be prefixed with `emblem-` (for instance, `emblem-drive.svg`).
- Put the emblem file inside the `emblems` folder of the icon theme folder (for instance, inside `/usr/share/icons/elementary-xfce/emblems/symbolic`).
- Update the icon theme cache by running:

  ```
  sudo gtk-update-icon-cache PATH-TO-THEME-FOLDER
  ```

  where `PATH-TO-THEME-FOLDER` contains the `index.theme` file.
- The emblem should be available if you click folder's *Properties...* → *Emblems* tab.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer at the link. However, I could not get the emblem to stay for a partition. This is documented in the comments there.
[How do I set emblems in Thunar without the GUI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/408743/how-do-i-set-emblems-in-thunar-without-the-gui)